# sync/async functions and frozen background loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cryptography, blockchain

I'm trying to dev a lottery game on top of a blockchain.
In server.js, this loop is intended to run "in background" and gather data on the blockchain every second.

```
let test = 0;
setTimeout(async function run() {
  test++;
  console.log(test);
  setTimeout(run, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

In an other module, I want to allow user to login with a keystore/password :

```
    socket.on("login", data => {
      helpers.checkCredentials(data).then(r => {
        //console.log(jwt.verify(r, process.env.JWT_PASS));
        //console.log(r);
        io.emit("login", r);
      });
    });
```

that calls checkCredentials :

```
const int4 = require("int4.js");

module.exports = async function(cred) {
  let account = null;
  let RPC = int4.rpc(process.env.URL_RPC);

  if (cred.keystore !== undefined && cred.password !== undefined) {
    try {
      account = int4.keystore.fromV3Keystore(cred.keystore, cred.password);
      console.log(account);
    } catch (e) {
      return "bad password or keystore";
    }
(...)
```

But the function `int4.keystore.fromV3Keystore` takes time to decrypt the keystore (approx. 5-7s) and during this time, my counter doesn't run, it's frozen.

I think I'm not familiar enough with practice of async functions, and despite a lot of readings I can't figure out why it freezes.
I tried to use `util` to `util.promisify` the `int4.keystore.fromV3Keystore`, hoping for some "async acting" but... nope.

Can you help me getting this "background" loop independant from the other functions ? Or making a clean code that would run every functions really asynchronously ?

Thanks a lot.
I use the beta lib https://github.com/intfoundation/int4.js for the INTChain testnet keystore decrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these async functions are running on the same thread. Promises and async/await is a way to get this one thread to run things asynchronously.

A result of this is that if any of these functions take too long before yielding execution (return or await on some other), the event loop gets stuck.

What you need is actual multithreading. You need to create a worker thread in which you run the long-running function and get the result back.

Here are some pointers to get started:
https://blog.logrocket.com/node-js-multithreading-what-are-worker-threads-and-why-do-they-matter-48ab102f8b10/
https://blog.logrocket.com/a-complete-guide-to-threads-in-node-js-4fa3898fe74f/

Comment: Thanks very much for you answer, I didn't know workers exist ! The first basic implementations for trying are very encouraging, I'm so happy !! Thanks again =D

Comment: You are welcome! Consider accepting this as the answer to the question if it helped you. Good luck!